# How to append filter dynamically in CSS

Tags: css

I have a web map showing rivers which are symbolized based on my CSS. For some of the rivers a brightness value is applied like that:

```
.river .large-river {
 border-left-color: blue;
 filter: brigthness(200%)
}
```

When a river object is selected, I want to highlight it and for all river elements, not depending if .river, .large-river, .small-river, etc., I attachted the [stroke='highlighted'] to the general class .river.

```
.river {
     stroke-width: 10px;
    }
    &[stroke='highlight']{
     stroke-width: 20px;
     filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 0 black) 
}
```

So rivers that are highlighted should get a larger stroke-width and a white shadow. This works, but only for those elements that do not have a brightness filter applied. I know I could change the brightness by just calculating the color value if brightness of 200% is applied to my color and set this as border-left-color. But I am curious if I can handle it like that, so to apply second filter, not knowing if the element already has a filter or not.

Any ideas?

If I add !important, than the filter with the white shadow is applied, but the brightness not anymore.

Comment: please provide a full code example including the html

Comment: I cannot as it is a huge project and it is time efforting creating another sample project. I think the issue can be clearly seen by the code I provided.

Comment: Sorry mate, this is not how Stack Overflow works. People are eager to help, but won't recreate the use case themselves. The lack of answers you got prove my point.

Comment: I hoped that someone knows about that problem, without testing it directly on a code.